# Methods to detect iron in highly concentrated ferric sulphate solutions

Tags: spectroscopy, titration, iron

I’m writing with a query related to reagents used to detect iron in highly concentrated ferric sulphate solutions.

I am currently exploring iron detection in both solutions of ferrous $\ce{(Fe^2+)}$ and ferric $\ce{(Fe^3+)}$ sulphate. I have had success with the detection of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ by performing potassium permanganate titrations which lead to accurate results. However, I am struggling to identify an appropriate reducing agent so that the method can be applied to solutions of ferric $\ce{(Fe^3+)}$ sulphate.

A potential option that I was considering was hydroxylamine hydrochloride. However, I am concerned about the potential quantities of $\ce{N2O}$ which may be produced at such high iron concentrations in the ferric sulphate I am using $(\approx \pu{18 gl^-1})$. Is anyone aware of this area of experimentation or aware of any such standard method for the detection of $\ce{Fe^3+}$ in this way?

Comment: Hydroxylamine is not a good choice. Because if you add an excess in the ferric solution, the excess will react with permanganate like the ferrous ion. Better use metallic iron (iron wire). In hot solution, $\ce{Fe}$  reacts with ferric ions according to $\ce{Fe + 2 Fe^{3+} -> 3 Fe^{2+}}$. Here an excess of the reducing reagent $\ce{Fe}$ will not react with permanganate. You also may use zinc $\ce{Zn}$ instead of  iron, according to $\ce{Zn + 2 Fe^{3+} -> Zn^{2+} + 2 Fe^{2+}}$, although zinc may also react with $\ce{H+}$ ions, creating .. too many $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions. Who knows ?

Comment: A classical titration of ferric ions is direct analysis with stannous chloride. Do you have analytical grade stannous chloride?